# Function to count lists of objects

Tags: javascript, function, class, object

Hey guys I am trying to build a function that counts the number of employees in each store. As you can see I have a class for stores, and a class for employees down below.

```
class Stores { 
    constructor(place, employees) {
        this.place = place;
        this.employees = employees;
    }
}
class Employees {
    constructor(name)  {
        this.name = name;
        this._EmployeeID = Employees.counter; //ID for the employee
    }
    get EmployeeID() {
        return this._EmployeeID
    }
    static get counter() {
        Employees._counter = (Employees._counter || 0) + 1;
        return Employees._counter
    }
}
```

Here I have listed some employees and stored them into lists

```
//employees 
const employee1 = new Employees("Torben")
const employee2 = new Employees("Mike")
const employee3 = new Employees("Rikke")
const employee4 = new Employees("Walid")
const employee5 = new Employees("Jens")
```

I have tried to build this function that loops over the objects, to count them, however for some reason I am not getting the correct result.

```
const copenhagenstore = new Stores("Copenhagenstore", {employee1, employee2, employee5})

function countemployees(store) {
    var length = 0;
    for(var key in store) {
        console.log(key)
        if(store.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
            ++length;
        }
    }
    return length;
};

console.log("the number of employees are: " + countemployees(copenhagenstore))
```

Below is my output, and as you can see, there should be 3 employees instead of two. I am pretty sure my function needs a bit of rework to account for this, and I was hoping that you guys could help me with that.

```
//OUTPUT
the number of employees are: 2
Stores {
  place: 'Copenhagenstore',
  employees: {
    employee1: Employees { name: 'Torben', _EmployeeID: 1 },
    employee2: Employees { name: 'Mike', _EmployeeID: 2 },
    employee5: Employees { name: 'Jens', _EmployeeID: 5 }
  }
}
```

Comment: This design strikes me as rather unusual for a few reasons. For one, if you're using an object, key it by id, e.g. `1` rather than `employee1` which is hard to use. For two `Stores` is plural but appears to encapsulate only a single store. Same with `Employees`.  Nonetheless, you probably meant to iterate over `for (var key in store.employees)` to count the number of employees in the store, not the number of properties in the outer store object. Your `console.log(key)` should tell you as much.

Comment: @WaisKamal Sure it is

Comment: @WaisKamal, it is valid syntax. It declares an object and is a shorthand for writing: `{"employee1": employee1, "employee2": employee2, "employee5": employee5}.` The reason the error occurs is because you are iterating over keys in `Store` not in the `store.employees`.

Comment: My bad. I didn't know of that ES6 feature.

Comment: Perfect thanks guys it worked

Comment: @BigManTing - In the long term you will continue to face issues like this because you are storing a list of objects with an object. A list is naturally carried by an array. You will find iteration over the list of employees much easier if you add them as a list (array) of employees rather than an object with objects. When instantiating a store replace `{emp1, emp2, emp3}` with `[emp1,emp2,emp3]` - then your `countemployees()` method is a one-liner: `return store.employees.length` - this simple change will make your life easier.